# Project build error: Non-readable POM C:\Users\u\Desktop\Selenium Andy\Automate_super User_login\pom.xml: input contained no data

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

At time when we add the dependencies in maven, it showing this error and after adding maven project it showing red line under the dependencies

```
Project build error: Non-readable POM C:\Users\u\Desktop\Selenium Andy\Automate_super User_login\pom.xml: input contained no data
```